# Need to install specific version of LAMP prerequisites on Ubuntu 14.04 desktop LTS

Tags: 14.04, apache2, php, mysql

I need to install below specific version on Ubuntu Linux (desktop 64-bit 14.04 LTS) how can I do that please help

- PHP 5.3.28
- Mysql 5.5.38
- Apache 2.2.26

Any help will be highly appreciable

Regards

Comment: why do you want apache2.2.26 instead of the latest version ?

Comment: ok help me to install like PHP 5.3.28 and latest version of Apache and Mysql

Comment: XAMPP Includes: Apache 2.4.12, MySQL 5.6.24, PHP 5.5.24

Comment: If this is for local web development where you want your local to be the same as the server, then I would suggest you have a look at Linux containers (LXC, docker, etc) or Virtual Machines (which will use more resources but is easier for a beginner).

Answer (score 0):

To install the latest Apache version, simly run these commands on Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

To use the PHP and MySQL versions you mentioned, you simply need to install them following this general rule:

```
apt-get install <package name>=<version>
```

But before doing that, I seriously do not understand why you need to use old software: new software versions are there not for fun but mainly for fixing security vulnerabilities (of which PHP is famous).

Finally, I prefer to quote from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/306487/install-php-5-3-on-ubuntu-13-04/306555#306555):

> Unless you do a full recompile from sources on the 14.04 platform, I'd
>   recommend NOT installing any pre-packaged version of an older PHP
>   version on a later OS. The reason is that there are many
>   incompatibilities between major releases and you'll be UNpleasently
>   surprised when things do not work.

Comment: begueradj, For a web application PHP 5.3.28 is mandatory to install. other versions are not compatible

Comment: @shaji I do web development too and I am usin PHP 5.6.8 without a problem :) the latest PHP version is 5.6.9

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Download XAMPP for Linux 5.5.24 & 5.6.8 click here [Download](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html)

Step 2 : open terminal ( Ctrl+Alt+t )

```
cd Downloads
sudo su
chmod 755 xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-1-installer.run
 ./xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-1-installer.run
```

Step 3 :

```
follow the instructions
```

Step 4.1 : Start Apache,MySQL

```
 /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Step 4.2 : stop Apache,MySQL

```
 /opt/lampp/lampp stop
```

Step 4.3 : restart Apache,MySQL

```
 /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

Step 5 : open web browser

```
http://localhost/
```

Comment: Hi Friends, I know the latest version of xampp and php. I need to install 5.3.28 for a application named SugarCRM. If I install latest version of xampp including latest version of php than installation showing compatibility error so I must need to install 5.3.28. Can any friend help me?