# Whether there is any compatibility issue for PHP 5.6 and Apache 2.4.51 on Ubuntu 18.04/20.04?

Tags: apache2, php

I am replicating an environment. The original environment contains Ubuntu 14.04, PHP 5.6 and Apache 2.4.51

Since 14.04 (and 16.04) is out of life, following are the possible Ubuntu OS that I can use:

1. 18.04
2. 20.04

I also know that PHP 7+ is supported on Ubuntu 16.04 onwards.

My question is that - whether there is any compatibility issue for PHP 5.6 and Apache 2.4.51 on each of the above Ubuntu OS versions?

I am asking because this link mentions it is not safe to use an older package on a newer OS: [Install PHP 5.3 on Ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/306487/install-php-5-3-on-ubuntu-13-04/306555#306555)

Note: I know how to install the php 5.6 via ppa:ondrej/php and Apache 2.4.51. This question is not about how to install them. Just about compatibility with these recent OS versions.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131111/discussion-on-question-by-variable-whether-there-is-any-compatibility-issue-for).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is safe and you should not have any compatibilty issues when installing the version from [ppa:ondrej](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2
sudo apt update
sudo apt install php5.6  apache2
```

While in general, you should be careful with PPAs, this is one of the few PPAs which I would recommend without a doubt.

Ondřej Surý is maintainer of the official PHP packages in Debian (and thus Ubuntu). He quite knows what he's doing.

This is what he says about himself on his website:

> I am a Debian Developer since year 2000, and I have been packaging PHP for Debian since PHP 5. [...] the PHP packages in my Ubuntu PPA and Debian DPA matches the official packages in Debian. Basically I am saying that you can’t get any closer than that.

---

Regarding your concerns due to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/306487/install-php-5-3-on-ubuntu-13-04/306555#306555): This is an 8 year old question. Back then, there was no PPA like this, and a downgrade was done manually (or with some script from the internet). You will install `php5.6` **alongside** any other version you have. It is true, that this might lead to dependency issues. But with ondrej's PPA, you won't have the issues, as the PPA will also deliver these dependencies.